# Structuring a beamer frame

Tags: beamer

i have a problem in a Beamer frame.

[image]

As you see in the left bottom corner there is a formula that isn't fitting very well, I would like to know if there is a way of fixing this without changing the letter size.

Here is the code for that frame:

```
\begin{frame}{Desarrollo $\zeta$}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Se calculan las constantes \pause
    \end{itemize}  
    \begin{equation}
          Overshoot\, (\%) = e^{-\frac{\zeta\pi}{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}}} * 100\%  \pause
    \end{equation}
  \begin{equation*}
      Overshoot = 20\% \pause
  \end{equation*} 

  Ahora se despeja para $\zeta$
  \begin{equation*}
      20\% = e^{-\frac{\zeta\pi}{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}}} * 100\% \pause
  \end{equation*}
  \begin{equation*}
      \zeta = \frac{\textnormal{ln(5)}}{\sqrt{\pi^2+\textnormal{[ln(5)]}^2}}
  \end{equation*} 

 Más generalmente: \pause

 \begin{equation*}
     \zeta = \frac{\textnormal{ln(X)}}{\sqrt{\pi^2+\textnormal{[ln(X)]}^2}
     \\ 
      \small{X = {[MP]}^-1}
     }
 \end{equation*}
\end{frame}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that's quite similar to the one in [@Zarko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/520881/5001). The main differences are (a) the use of inline-style fractions instead of `\frac` notation, (b) the use of `\exp(...)` notation instead of `e^{...}`, and (c) the use of a *single* `align` environment along with two `\intertext` statements.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Desarrollo $\zeta$}
\begin{itemize}
\item Se calculan las constantes 
\begin{align}
   Overshoot\, (\%) &= \exp(-\zeta\pi\big/\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}\,) \cdot 100\%   \\
   Overshoot &= 20\%\notag 
\intertext{Ahora se despeja para $\zeta$:}
   20\% &= \exp(-\zeta\pi\big/\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}\,) \cdot 100\% \notag  \\
   \zeta &= \ln 5\big/\sqrt{\pi^2+[\ln 5]^2} \notag \\ 
\intertext{Más generalmente:}
   \zeta &= \ln(X)\big/\sqrt{\pi^2+[\ln X]^2} \notag\\
   X &= [MP]^{-1} \notag
\end{align}
\end{itemize}  
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for giving credit to an earlier answer which has overlap with yours,

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat - Many thanks! I guess it still shows that I was once an academic researcher: I simply cannot help but give credit to prior work in any field I'm working on... Plus, Zarko's answer is very goodi in its own rights!

Answer (score 2):

- you not provide your document preamble, so the frame layout with suggested MWE is different from yours
- for equations are used `align` environment defined in `amsmath` package
- LaTeX has defined operator `ln`
- for units is sensible to use `siunitx` package

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Desarrollo $\zeta$}
    \begin{itemize}
\item Se calculan las constantes \pause
    \begin{align}
\text{Overshoot (\%)}   
    & = \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\zeta\pi}{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}}\ast\SI{100}{\%}}          \\   \pause
    & = \SI{20}{\%}   \notag \pause
    \end{align}
Ahora se despeja para $\zeta$
  \begin{align*}
\SI{20}{\%} & = \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\zeta\pi}{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}}}\ast\SI{100}{\%}  \\   \pause
    \zeta   & = \frac{\ln(5)}{\sqrt{\pi^2+ [\ln(5)]^2}}
  \end{align*}
Más generalmente: \pause
    \begin{align*}
\zeta & = \frac{\ln(X)}{\sqrt{\pi^2+ [\ln(X)]^2}}\\
    X & = [MP]^{-1}
    \end{align*}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]